# void pointer to vector elements

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I want to have a void pointer to a vector.

```
void *para;
vector<double> x(2);
x[0] = 0;
x[1] = 1;
para = &x;
```

I can now use the vector like this.

```
vector<double> k = *(static_cast<vector<double>*>(para));
cout << k[0] << "\n";
```

Now I want to access the elements of the vectors through the pointer. How can I do that? But now I want to get the elements of the vector x, directly via the void pointer para, without using the new vector k. Something like this:

```
double k = ??? // here should be the element of x via para
```

Thank's in advance.

Comment: You can't really know where those elements are. You certainly cannot get to them by incrementing `para`.

Comment: `(*static_cast<vector<double>*>(para))[0]` would be the obvious answer, but I'm guessing that's not what you're after. Can you explain more clearly what you do want?

Comment: Technically, `(*(static_cast<vector<double>*>(para)))[0]` or `(static_cast<vector<double>*>(para))->operator[](0))`, though I'd argue that doing either is SUPER BAD PRACTICE OMG WHYYYYYY.

Comment: Why is this SUPER BAD PRACTICE OMG.

Comment: You can't access anything via a void pointer without casting and in robust code there should be a minimum use of casting so why anyone would say that he "wants to have a void pointer to a vector" is totally beyond me.

Comment: I have a function that calculates some complicated equation depending on three acceleration field. These acceleration fields are all of the type: vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>> accel; When I call the funtion I don't want to call it with all three acceleration field but give a void pointer to it which points to the three fields. For the calculation in the funtion I need to access the elements of the vector vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>> accel; Is their a better way????

Comment: @stefaanv there are C API where you pass void * as a cookie for example. Is that a good enough reason for you?

Comment: @Slava: then you just pass your (non-void) pointer to the API and let him get on with his business.

Comment: @stefaanv you pass your (non-void) pointer as cookie and then you get it back as `void *` and you need to use it. Think about `pthread_create` for example.

Comment: @Jojia That still doesn't explain why you would want a `void` pointer. Why don't you use a pointer of the proper type? Perhaps you should ask about the problem you're actually trying to solve (it sounds like you want to avoid passing large objects as parameters).

Comment: @Slava: then you don't "want a void pointer", but you are "forced to cast one back".  In the specific case of pthread_create, use std::thread if you don't need the advanced features of pthread.  But reading the edit of your answer, I assume we think similarly.

Comment: @molbdnilo: exactly I don't want to pass large objects as parameters. Do you have any idea how I could do that in a better way???

Comment: @Jojia There are many ways depending on the particular problem. I suggest you post a new question (don't update this one) that explains your situation in more detail.

Comment: @Jojia You could just pass a `vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>>` pointer, which would be type safe and you can avoid a *lot* of potential bugs that way. It would also be more readable and just easier in general.

Answer (score 3):

> Now I want to access the elements of the vectors through the pointer.

This has two steps: reinterpret the pointer as a vector, then access elements.

> How can I do that? But now I want to get the elements of the vector x, directly via the void pointer para, without using the new vector k.

```
void *para;
vector<double> x(2);
para = &x;

// step 1: reinterpret the pointer as a vector
auto *voidToVector = reinterpret_cast< vector<double>* >(para);

// step 2: access elements
double k = (*voidToVector)[0];
```

That said, please DON'T store data in your application as `void*`. Every time you do, you can assume that a developer will probably see it later and die a bit inside (and that developer may even be you).

Edit:

> For the calculation in the function, I need to access the elements of the vector, vector>>> accel; Is there a better way????

Consider this:

```
class FourDimensionalVector
{
public:
    FourDimensionalVector(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t z, std::size_t a)
    : d1{x}, d2{y}, d3{z}, d4{a}
    , data{ d1 * d2 * d3 * d4 }
    {
    }

    // ALL access to the vector elements can/should be done through this
    double& operator()(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, std::size_t z, std::size_t a)
    {
        assert(d1 > x); // same for the other dimensions
        return data[x * d1 + y * d2 + z * d3 + a];
    }

    // implement other interface elements here (iteration access, reading the size,
    // resetting the values, etc.

private:
    std::size_t d1, d2, d3, d4;
    std::vector<double> data; // store flattened data
};
```

With this, you just pass a reference to the data as a parameter, and edit it as needed. I'm not sure the indexing logic is OK (and the code is incomplete), but the idea is the same.

Client code:

```
void YourFunction(FourDimensionalVector& fdv)
{
    fdv[2, 3, 4, 0] = fdv[2, 3, 4, 0] + 0.38;
}
```

This solution is strongly typed, efficient and clean (it avoids the casting completely and the void*).

**[edit by Jojia]**: But what is the difference between your solution and this one

```
vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>> Xaccel;

void initialize(&Xaccel); //This function initializes values for all elements of Xaccel

void myfunction(&Xaccel){
double x = Xaccel[0][0][0][0];
}
```

I don't see any difference to your solution. BUT: I thought passing these large objects to the function myfunction might be a problem. Is that correct?

**[edit by utnapistim]**:
From a semantical point of view, they are the same: both send the same data to the function and allocate the same memory (my solution also stores dimensions, but whatever).

From a maintenance/reusability/testability/modularity point of view, they are quite different: my solution abstracts away the fact that your four dimensional matrix is a vector (of vector of vector ... ).

This will allow you to write your client code using a 4d matrix interface (which you can implement to match the needs of your client code) instead of a vector, and allow you to define your operations in terms of a matrix.

For example, the `vector<vector<vector<double>>>` code can be used to create a sparse/asymetrical matrix (with the first line in the outer vector being three times longer than the second line and so on). The matrix class would prevent that by cutting access to the vector.

If you choose to keep the `vector<vector...>` solution, at least typedef it:

```
typedef vector<vector<vector<double>>> FourDMatrix;

FourDMatrix Xaccel;

void initialize(FourDMatrix& Xaccel);
void myfunction(FourDMatrix& Xaccel);
```

Comment: Correction: The developer will see it, waste lots of time figuring out why it was done this way, **then** die a bit inside, and then spend yet more time patching the code so that it uses the better construct it should have used right from the start. And chances are this developer **will** be you, in a year or two. ;-)

Comment: @ DevSolar Please tell me then: What would be a better way. I want to do the following: I have a function that calculates some complicated equation depending on three acceleration fields. These acceleration fields are all of the type: vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>> accel; When I call the funtion I don't want to call it with all three acceleration field but give a void pointer to it which points to the three fields. For the calculation in the funtion, I need to access the elements of the vector, vector<vector<vector<vector<double>>>> accel; Is there a better way????

Comment: @Jojia, I am adding an edit to my answer to address your questions.

Comment: @utnapistim I edited your solution. Because I think there is no difference to mine. What do you think????

Comment: @Jojia Questions should be asked in the comments, not by editing the answer. If you need to post code, you can post it to a paste site (like http://pastebin.com/) and post the link in the comment. Also, to answer your question, when you pass a reference (as in the example you gave, if we correct the syntax a bit), the object is not copied. It is similar to a pointer in this way. Internally, it only passes the memory location of the object to the function, it doesn't make a copy of the object.

Answer (score 2):

In this line you create a copy:

```
vector<double> k = *(static_cast<vector<double>*>(para));
```

So one of the solution would be to use reference instead:

```
vector<double> &k = *(static_cast<vector<double>*>(para));
k[0] = 123;
```

Or pointer

```
vector<double> *pk = static_cast<vector<double>*>(para);
(*pk)[0] = 123; // but usage is more explicit, so reference would be better
```

I assume you know what you are doing and you really need to pass vector through a `void *`. One of the reasons could be passing pointer to vector as a cookie to C API that expects `void *`. Note there is very low chance to have a good reason to use `void *` in c++ itself, you should use `boost::any` or `boost::variant` for type safety.